# SQL - Moving data from one table into another - syntax error: unexpected 'DELETED'

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to move data from one table into another which already contains data.

I found online that the best was to do it is with this SQL call:

```
DELETE FROM table_1
OUTPUT DELETED.*
INTO table_2;
```

However I get:

> SQL compilation error: syntax error line 2 at position 7 unexpected 'DELETED'

I am running this in Snowflake.

Is there a reason it is not working?

Comment: Where did you get that reference code? Looks like SQL Server (maybe Snowflake supports it too), which would load your deleted records into an already declared table variable called table_2. What are you trying to do? Do you want to delete all the existing data and replace it, or just insert the new stuff?

Comment: What does the (official) documentation say?

Comment: trying to remove data from the first table and move it to the second table (both tables have identical columns). I think i should be able to do it using INSERT INTO ... SELECT but just wondering why this solution doesn't work as i've seen it suggested in a few posts on here

Comment: So once all is said done you want table1 to be empty, and table2 to have the data that was originally in table1?

Comment: I don't believe that `OUTPUT DELETED` is an option in Snowflake. Honestly, even if it was, I would be way to nervous to trust it. Instead INSERT the data into the target table, check that everything is 100%, then perform the DELETE operation on the source table.

Comment: IF you want to have the table table_1 to have only what is present in table_2 then you can Truncate table_1 and insert into table_1 select * from table_2  Or  drop table_1 and create table_1 as select * from table_2.

Answer (score 0):

you can DELETE and the INSERT from the deleted table as it was [BEFORE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/at-before) the delete (using time travel), and never missing any rows.

The reason this works, is Snowflake is immutable database, so timetravel is the fancy name for (every change every made is kept), thus the order does not "matter" because the prior state of the deleted/truncated table, is not lost.

### setup:

```
create or replace table t1(id, val) as
    select * from values
        (1,10),
        (1,11), 
        (1,12), 
        (2,20), 
        (2,21);

create or replace table t2 like t1;
```

quick check (which we will reuse):

```
select 't1' as tab, * from t1
union all
select 't2', * from t2;
```

[image]

### the code:

now the two command block

```
-- BLOCK START
delete from t1;

insert into t2 select * from t1 before(STATEMENT => LAST_QUERY_ID());
-- BLOCK END
```

these will want to run on the same session/connection to work.

then check again:

[image]

now if there is a magic insert that happens between those two commands, on another thread (I will use another worksheet)

```
insert into t1 
    select * from values
        (3,30),
        (3,31);
```

[image]

after the second block command runs, we do a check:

[image]

nice and thread safe.